# Preprocess SCSS with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml, sass, asset-pipeline

I have an app that has some categories: Tomato, Orange, Banana.
Each category has it's own color saved in the database: FF0000, FF6600, FFFF00.
There're also some posts in the app that belong to a category.

I want HAML and/or SASS to generate classes from the category names/color, like:

```
.tomato header { background-color: #FF0000; }
.tomato aside  { background-color: lighten(#FF0000, 0.5); }

.orange header { background-color: #FF6600; }
.orange aside  { background-color: lighten(#FF6600, 0.5); }

.banana header { background-color: #FFFF00; }
.banana aside  { background-color: lighten(#FFFF00, 0.5); }
```

As you can see I want to loop the `categories` table and use SASS functions listed [here](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html). Here's not working example/pseudo-code:

```
- @categories.each |category|
  :sass
    .#{category.slug} header { background-color: ##{category.color}; }
    .#{category.slug} aside  { background-color: lighten(##{category.color}, 0.5); }
```

Any tips how I could achieve that?

Things to keep in mind:

- I don't want inline (in post) stylesheets
- I use HAML and SASS (SCSS style)
- I run Rails 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Use the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline to first run your code as ERB and then as Sass (so the filename would be something like application.css.sass.erb) and make a variable available to the ERB that you could iterate over and create some Sass. Will that work in your situation?

Comment: In the header part of the website I have `= stylesheet_link_tag 'categories'`. In `app/assets/stylesheets` directory I have file called `categories.css.scss.erb`. That file has the ERB code to loop the `@categories` instance variable. When running I get the following error: `The error occurred while evaluating nil.each` So `@categories` is nil. I'm sure `@categories` is not nil.